# How can i compress large directories in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, download, compression, large-files

I have a directory with size of more than 400 MB that contains several files. I want compress this folder to a zip file and then provide a download link for user. How can I do his work in ASP.Net?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) and zip the entire directory!

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
  zip.AddDirectory(@"YourProjectDirectoryPath", "ZipName");
  zip.Save("Path");
}
```

It's easy to do! I hope this can help you.

Comment: please check this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865419/compress-large-directories-with-dotnetzip-in-asp-net